# How to implement shortcuts in an application

Tags: android, view, android-activity, host, shortcut

I am building a home application and want to be able to put shortcuts on the main screen,  just like how the default home applications do it.  Can anyone help me with this.  If not then can someone atleast point me towards some resources that will help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you want since your question seems a bit broad. However, one tip would be to take a look at the source code for the launcher.

[Link to old launcher source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=summary)

[Link to new launcher source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=summary)

Or take a look at launcher plus:

http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/

Edit: kernel.org was hacked.
[Link to old launcher code - new link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git)

[Link to new launcher code - new link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/)

Comment: The first two links are down.